# can't change div element to canvas using html2canvas in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html2canvas

I use  [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com) and  this is how I declare js files and css in Master Page

```
     <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/html2canvas.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

In My content page ,

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<script type="text/javascript">
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("mainDiv"), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    });
</script>    
<div id="mainDiv" style="background-color: #CCFF66; border-style: solid; border-color: #000000;
    width: 300px; height: 300px;display:block">
</div>
```

but it doesn't work with this code `document.getElementById("mainDiv")` , but when I change to `document.body`

```
 html2canvas(document.body, { 
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
```

It works , it append image to the bottom of body .
But I don't want to convert the whole body of my page .
I Just want to convert `DIV` to canvas .
How can I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dude, your missing the `$(document).ready ( function () { ...  })` statement in your asp page , hence its not initialised

```
  $(document).ready ( function () { 
      html2canvas(document.getElementById("mainDiv"), {
           onrendered: function (canvas) {
              document.body.appendChild(canvas);
           }
       });
   });
```

Happy Coding :)